# How does the downcasting by as! work for same type?

Tags: ios, macos, swift

In the following code, downcasting by `as!` is failed for same type.
Doesn't Swift allow downcasting for same type or not?

```
class base {
    var a = 1
}

class derived : base {

}

let a: base? = base()
let b = a as! base     // error occur!
println("\(b.a)")
```

Error message:
`error: downcast from 'base?' to 'base' only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use '!'?
    let b = a as! base
        ~ ^   ~~~~`

If I modify an above code like the following, there is no problem.

```
let a: base? = derived()
let b = a as! derived
println("\(b.a)")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the define of `DownCasting` in swift

> Downcasting
>
> A constant or variable of a certain class type may actually refer to an instance of a **subclass** behind the scenes. Where you believe this is the case, you can try to downcast to the subclass type with a type cast operator (as? or as!).

So,if the type is same,that is not DownCasting.

[Swift document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this  :

```
let b = a!
```

Comment: I also know that it's work well with the code you suggest. but, your code is *ONLY* about forced unwrapping. `as!` is about *downcasting* with forced unwrapping.

Comment: Yes, It is forced unwrapping. The `a` was a `base` already, so you don't need to use `as`(downcasting).

Comment: A point of the question is that downcasting by `as!` for same type is legal or not.